# Is MapReduce the Right Option When Dealing with Volatile Collections That Need to Be Joined Many times in Realtieme?

Tags: mongodb, join, mapreduce

I need to join 2 collections... so I've tried the `map-reduce` feature provided by MongoDB. Given the following collections:

`transactions`:

```
{ "_id": 1, "userId": 1000, "amount": 0.75, "btcAddress": "1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW62i" }
{ "_id": 2, "userId": 2000, "amount": 0.55, "btcAddress": "1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW63i" }
```

`users`:

```
{ "_id": 1000, "username": "joe", "email": "joe@domain.com" }
{ "_id": 2000, "username": "tim", "email": "tim@domain.com" }
```

I need to produce something like this:

```
{ "_id": 1, "username": "joe", "email": "joe@domain.com", "amount": 0.75, "btcAddress": "1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW62i" }
{ "_id": 2, "username": "tim", "email": "tim@domain.com", "amount": 0.55, "btcAddress": "1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW63i" }
```

The documentation is clear, so I just defined the mapping functions like this...

```
transactions_map = function() {
    ...
}

users_map = function() {
    ...
}
```

... and the reduce (merge) function like this:

```
r = function(key, values) {
  ...
}
```

As the final step, I just invoking `mapReduce`:

```
res = db.transactions.mapReduce(transactions_map, r, {out: {reduce : 'joined'}});
res = db.users.mapReduce(users_map, r, {out: {reduce : 'joined'}});
```

This works and produces the expected result... but there some considerations. `mapReduce` generates a temporary collection and in my case this raises a concurrency issue. I guess I need to drop the temporary collection before invoking `mapRedudce` again... but this process may be triggered many times a hour and by many users simultaneously. `mapReduce` seems to be designed for statistics, while I need something very similar to a SQL `join` in real-time since the `transactions` collection changes very often.

Are there alternatives to `mapReduce`? Or are there at least implementation strategies to deal with use cases like mine?

Comment: "Are there alternatives to mapReduce?" - yes. They are called relational databases.

Comment: Not really sure what you "want" someone to say. The correct answer AFAIK is to not use "joins" with MongoDB but model so that you actually get what you want in a single query. Your question does not really state what you ultimately need to do. So I think you just get bad answers. Or needless commentary.

Comment: I was looking for a way to emulate SQL joins... and mapReduce does it, but what hurts me is the fact it generates a temporary collection that needs to be dropped before re-running mapReduce. Furthermore I don't think mapReduce is the ideal solution when the query needs to be performed again and again by many users simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only to make a join as your example, I think **mapReduce** is unnecessary.
I try on this way.

```
var result = [];
db.transactions.find().forEach(function(e) {
    var user = db.users.findOne({_id: e.userId}, {_id:0});
    delete e.userId;
    if (user) {
        for (var x in user) {
            e[x] = user[x];
        }
    }
    result.push(e);
});
```

If the result is very large and you want to save to a temporary collection, you can save the new document into a collection named as `new ObjectId().str` among the looping to avoid simultaneous impact.

Comment: Yes, it works. Now I have to port it to reactivemongo, hoping it's not too complicated. Anyway thanks you very much.